# Input userform text valie to next empty cell to the right

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Looking to enter dates from my userform into contact 1 then if i put another date for the same customer i want it to go to contact 2, contact 3 and so on. I want to be able to do it even if i clicked on customer 6. Essentially this should go to the next empty contact to the right.

**Client List**

[image]

**UserForm**

[image]

Here is my VBA

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contacts")
    Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lending")
    Set WS3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Deposits")
    Set WS4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Client Notes")

    x = Me.lblRow 'current row

    ws.Cells(x, 4) = Me.clientname
    WS4.Cells(x, 5) = Me.clientnotes
    WS2.Cells(x, 5) = Me.mortgage1.Value
    WS2.Cells(x, 8) = Me.mortgage2.Value
    WS2.Cells(x, 13) = Me.helocrate.Value
    WS2.Cells(x, 14) = Me.helocbalance.Value
    WS2.Cells(x, 16) = Me.bline.Value
    WS2.Cells(x, 17) = Me.blinerate.Value
    WS2.Cells(x, 18) = Me.bloan.Value
    WS2.Cells(x, 19) = Me.bloanrate.Value
    WS3.Cells(x, 5) = Me.cchecking.Value
    WS3.Cells(x, 6) = Me.csavings.Value
    WS3.Cells(x, 8) = Me.cdbalance.Value
    WS3.Cells(x, 9) = Me.cdrate.Value
    WS3.Cells(x, 10) = Me.bchecking.Value
    WS3.Cells(x, 11) = Me.bsavings.Value
    WS2.Cells(x, 7) = Me.mrate1.Value
    WS2.Cells(x, 6) = Me.mortgagerate1.Value
    WS2.Cells(x, 9) = Me.mortgagerate2.Value
    ws.Cells(x, 5) = Me.cdates1.Value

    Unload Me
    ActiveSheet.Protect "password"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a loop to find the first empty "Contact **N**" column. A bit of code tidy up as well here. Note this will not stop looking pass the 6th Contact.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim x As Long, c As Long
    Const CONTACT_START As Long = 5 ' Column E
    Const COL_PER_CONTACT As Long = 3 ' Columns per Contact

    x = CLng(Me.lblRow) 'current row

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contacts")
        c = CONTACT_START
        ' Look for first empty one
        Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(x, c))
            c = c + COL_PER_CONTACT
        Loop
        .Cells(x, c) = Me.clientname
        .Cells(x, c + 1) = Me.cdates1.Value
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lending")
        .Cells(x, 5) = Me.mortgage1.Value
        .Cells(x, 6) = Me.mortgagerate1.Value
        .Cells(x, 7) = Me.mrate1.Value
        .Cells(x, 8) = Me.mortgage2.Value
        .Cells(x, 9) = Me.mortgagerate2.Value
        .Cells(x, 13) = Me.helocrate.Value
        .Cells(x, 14) = Me.helocbalance.Value
        .Cells(x, 16) = Me.bline.Value
        .Cells(x, 17) = Me.blinerate.Value
        .Cells(x, 18) = Me.bloan.Value
        .Cells(x, 19) = Me.bloanrate.Value
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Deposits")
        .Cells(x, 5) = Me.cchecking.Value
        .Cells(x, 6) = Me.csavings.Value
        .Cells(x, 8) = Me.cdbalance.Value
        .Cells(x, 9) = Me.cdrate.Value
        .Cells(x, 10) = Me.bchecking.Value
        .Cells(x, 11) = Me.bsavings.Value
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Client Notes")
        .Cells(x, 5) = Me.clientnotes
    End With

    Unload Me
    ActiveSheet.Protect "password"
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much, works like a charm, you even cleaned up my horrible vba coding. You have saved me hours of time.

Comment: question, how can I skip cells that are left blank if a user doesn't enter a date in contact attempt 1. Currently contact 2 dates are going into contact 1 dates, if contact 1 dates were left blank

Comment: Don't know your workflow, but the code checks for first empty Contacts column groups in "Contacts" worksheet. The `Me.cdates1.Value` should be in the right place if `Me.clientname` isn't empty (which is placed in column Contact X).